# Android Web Site make Phone Call with IVR parameters

Tags: android, html, web, ivr

I created a web site with some phone numbers inside in which I'm using the tag like:

```
<a href="Tel:+55555555555,20703%23,109837%23,2%23,,1" >Home</a>
```

where:

- `Tel:+55555555555` is the phone number,
- `20703%23,109837%23,2%23,,1` are parameters

I need send the parameters to a IVR. It works on all versions below Android 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Tel:` is incorrect, use instead the scheme `tel:`

```
<a href="tel:+55555555555,20703%23,109837%23,2%23,,1">Home</a>
```

and it can work with no problem

Read this article:

[How to create click-to-call links for mobile browsers](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers)

> **The tel: scheme**
>
> The first de facto standard (copied from the Japanese i-Mode
>   standards) is to use the tel: scheme. It was proposed as a standard in
>   the RFC 5341, but be careful because most of the parameters proposed
>   there do not work on any device.
>
> Today, we can find support for tel: URI-scheme in almost every mobile
>   device, including: Safari on iOS, Android Browser (image above), webOS
>   Browser (image above), Symbian browser, Internet Explorer, Opera Mini
>   and low-end devices browsers.
>
> The very basic and simple syntax is:
>
> ```
> <a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>
> ```
>
> If the user activates a call link she will receive a confirmation
>   alert asking whether to place the call, showing the full number. This
>   is to avoid frauds tricking the user into calling another country or a
>   premium number.
>
> I recommend inserting the phone number in the international format:
>   the plus sign (+), the country code, the local area code, and the
>   local number. We do not really know where our visitors will be
>   located. If they are in the same country, or even in the same local
>   area, the international format will still work.